# How to rearrange class members using Coderush Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush-xpress

I've installed coderush express for visual studio 2010 and can't figure out how to rearrange my class members so that they are arranged by convention.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/coderushx) does not allow you to rearrange class members out-of-the-box. This can be done using the [Member Organizer](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/04/organizing-source-code-and-sorting-class-members-using-coderush/) feature shipped in the [CodeRush Pro](http://www.devexpress.com/coderush) version. The Member Organizer is an open source plug-in, so you may install it into CodeRush Xpress later. You might also ask [DevExpress Support Team](http://www.devexpress.com/sc) to send this plug-in to you.

Comment: where can I get actual copy compatible with CodeRush Xpress 11.2.13?

Comment: Official answer:This plug-in will be loaded correctly only if the full CodeRush is installed http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q526757